# How do you pronounce "melee"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

I've heard meelee, meyley (maylay), and mehlay. Is there any "correct" way to pronounce it in the U.S.?

Comment: It's not 'mee-lee'. It is inspired by the French pronunciation, which is mostly like 'may-lay'.

Comment: Oh man... thank you for asking this question. I always cringe when I hear gamers say "mee lee" >_<

Comment: Just like they do on Super Smash Bros., and I used the same intonation ;)

Comment: All words taken from other languages and nations (including place names) are liable to change in their novel context. Such changes can affect meaning(s), spellings, pronunciations and the situations they are used in. So while some US English pronunciations of *mêlée* are closer to the original French pronunciation than others, I would not rush to call any of them *wrong*. Their divergences from the French usage and pronunciation are a natural part of the process of being assimilated into English; they certainly aren't worth getting worked up about, particularly as that would be futile anyway.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

NOAD gives these pronunciations:

> **melee** |ˈmāˌlā; māˈlā| (also mêlée)

Which are, in order of usage, *may*-lay, may-*lay*, and also muh-*lay*

Comment: This answer gets my approval.

Comment: In other words - **Not** mee-lee

Comment: Very much *meh-lay* in the UK.

Comment: The OED3 lists the pronunciation of [mêlée](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/116086) as Brit.  /ˈmɛleɪ/,  /mɛˈleɪ/, U.S.  /ˈmeɪleɪ/.  It doesn’t even list the weird spelling denuded of proper diacritics. And it doesn’t use invented fako anti-IPA. IPA exists because it is an international standard. This SE site should certainly be using it.

Comment: @tchrist: Availability of IPA is on a computer-by-computer basis, both for producing and rendering. Until it becomes universally available (and easier to use), alternatives are necessary. And are you saying that the OED3 is the only reference source we should use?

Comment: @Robusto No, I am saying that ɪᴘᴀ is the only *phonetic transcription language* we should use. Otherwise, just resort to “rhymes with” or something. **Don’t use *nonstandard* phonetic symbols.** Anyway,  there is no excuse not to have ɪᴘᴀ on a modern computer.

Comment: @tchrist: "There is no excuse not to have IPA on a modern computer." That's a bold statement. Does it include notebooks, tablets, and smart phones?

Comment: @Robusto I stand by what I wrote.

Comment: [IPA is overkill](http://learnenglishorstarve.wordpress.com/respell/) in most cases. Yes, even here.

Answer (score 15):

Melee comes from French, to fight, and is pronounced by French rules, with accents it is mêlée, which in English the e-circonflex would be more like "e" in Greg, and ée would be "ay" as in "gray".

Most commonly English speakers butcher it however they like, so no, there is not one correct way to fail to pronounce the French word. It's a potayto-potahtoh thing.

Most commonly I hear "Meh-lay", from US video-game users who use the term to refer to close-ranged weapons like knives, in first person shooters.

Comment: Is appealing to etymology really a legitimate way to determine pronunciation?  Do you pronounce "two" as "twah"?

Comment: Only reason I don't pronounce it "melly" anymore, as a word I read before hearing, is because of Super Smash Brothers Melee. Before that, I thought that the "meh-lay" attack in Halo and "melly" were two different, but probably related, words...

Comment: @kitukwfyer -- "melly"?  That's hilarious, it *should* be pronounced melly!

Comment: Is that "melly" like "smelly" without the s? That's awesome.

Comment: **David Beckham:** *"Victoria, how many Mels were there in the Spice Girls?"* **Victoria:** *"Two David. Mel B and Mel C."* **David:** *"Oh. Only I heard on the news there was a Mel A outside a night-club last night."* (From "The Big impression", BBC)

Comment: It's not mere etymology, it's a loan word.

Comment: As for butcherings, I've heard may-lay and even mee-lee

Answer (score 10):

Using IPA, the American pronunciation is /ˈmeɪleɪ/, while the British pronunciation is /ˈmɛleɪ/, as reported by the *New Oxford American Dictionary* and the *Oxford English Dictionary*.